# layer Normalization in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

shouldn't the layer normalization of `x = torch.tensor([[1.5,0,0,0,0]])` be `[[1.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5]]` ? according to this paper [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450.pdf) and the equation from the [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#layernorm). But the `torch.nn.LayerNorm` gives `[[ 1.7320, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773]]`

Here is the example code:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1.5,.0,.0,.0]])
layerNorm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(4, elementwise_affine = False)

y1 = layerNorm(x)

mean = x.mean(-1, keepdim = True)
var = x.var(-1, keepdim = True)
y2 = (x-mean)/torch.sqrt(var+layerNorm.eps)
```

where:

```
y1 == tensor([[ 1.7320, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773]])
y2 == tensor([[ 1.5000, -0.5000, -0.5000, -0.5000]])
```

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
var = x.var(-1, keepdim = True)
```

you should use

```
var = x.var(-1, keepdim = True, unbiased=False)
```

This will produce identical result as pytorch, full code:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1.5,.0,.0,.0]])
layerNorm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(4, elementwise_affine = False)
y1 = layerNorm(x)
mean = x.mean(-1, keepdim = True)
var = x.var(-1, keepdim = True, unbiased=False)
y2 = (x-mean)/torch.sqrt(var+layerNorm.eps)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another simplified implementation of a Layer Norm layer with bare PyTorch.

```py
from typing import Tuple
import torch


def layer_norm(
    x: torch.Tensor, dim: Tuple[int], eps: float = 0.00001
) -> torch.Tensor:
    mean = torch.mean(x, dim=dim, keepdim=True)
    var = torch.square(x - mean).mean(dim=dim, keepdim=True)
    return (x - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + eps)


def test_that_results_match() -> None:
    dims = (1, 2)
    X = torch.normal(0, 1, size=(3, 3, 3))

    indices = torch.tensor(dims)
    normalized_shape = torch.tensor(X.size()).index_select(0, indices)
    orig_layer_norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(normalized_shape)

    y = orig_layer_norm(X)
    y_hat = layer_norm(X, dim=dims)

    assert torch.allclose(y, y_hat)
```

Note, that original implementation also has trainable parameters  and **β** (see the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html)).

Comment: Note: In the variance calculation step in layer_norm() written by @mozharovsky, we can also use torch.var(x, dim=dim, keepdim=True, unbiased=False)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple correct example:

```py
x = torch.normal(0, 1, [5])
mean = x.sum(axis = 0)/(x.shape[0])
std = (((x - mean)**2).sum()/(x.shape[0])).sqrt()

print((x - mean)/std)
# tensor([ 0.8972, -0.1496, -1.5654,  1.2419, -0.4242])

print(nn.LayerNorm(5, elementwise_affine = False)(x.unsqueeze(0)))
# tensor([ 0.8972, -0.1496, -1.5654,  1.2419, -0.4242])
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, the code should be as:

```
...
var = x.mean((x-mean)**2, -1, keepdim = True)
...
```

hopefully this is helpful to anyone, who stumbles on this same mistake.

Comment: I would say the easiest-to-follow implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/066e3ed953dd0bb0f3ca4889bbb7835675afb11f/aten/src/ATen/native/cpu/layer_norm_kernel.cpp#L16-L67). `rstd` usually stands for "relative standard deviation".

Comment: thanks, I should just have looked at the source code from the beginning.