# Understanding torch.nn.LayerNorm in nlp

Tags: python, pytorch, normalization

I'm trying to understanding how `torch.nn.LayerNorm` works in a nlp model. Asuming the input data is a batch of sequence of word embeddings:

```
batch_size, seq_size, dim = 2, 3, 4
embedding = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_size, dim)
print("x: ", embedding)

layer_norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(dim)
print("y: ", layer_norm(embedding))

# outputs:
"""
x:  tensor([[[ 0.5909,  0.1326,  0.8100,  0.7631],
         [ 0.5831, -1.7923, -0.1453, -0.6882],
         [ 1.1280,  1.6121, -1.2383,  0.2150]],

        [[-0.2128, -0.5246, -0.0511,  0.2798],
         [ 0.8254,  1.2262, -0.0252, -1.9972],
         [-0.6092, -0.4709, -0.8038, -1.2711]]])
y:  tensor([[[ 0.0626, -1.6495,  0.8810,  0.7060],
         [ 1.2621, -1.4789,  0.4216, -0.2048],
         [ 0.6437,  1.0897, -1.5360, -0.1973]],

        [[-0.2950, -1.3698,  0.2621,  1.4027],
         [ 0.6585,  0.9811, -0.0262, -1.6134],
         [ 0.5934,  1.0505, -0.0497, -1.5942]]],
       grad_fn=<NativeLayerNormBackward0>)
"""
```

From the [document's description](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html), my understanding is that the mean and std are computed by all embedding values per sample. So I try to compute `y[0, 0, :]` manually:

```
mean = torch.mean(embedding[0, :, :])
std = torch.std(embedding[0, :, :])
print((embedding[0, 0, :] - mean) / std)
```

which gives `tensor([ 0.4310, -0.0319,  0.6523,  0.6050])` and that's not the right output. I want to know what is the right way to compute `y[0, 0, :]`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pytorch [layer norm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html) states mean and std calculated over last D dimensions. Based on this as I expect for `(batch_size, seq_size, embedding_dim)` here calculation should be over `(seq_size, embedding_dim)` for layer norm as last 2 dimensions excluding batch dim.

A similar question and answer with layer norm implementation can be found here, [layer Normalization in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59830168/layer-normalization-in-pytorch).

In some paper below it shows different layer norm application in NLP.

##### Explanation of [Intance vs Layer vs Group Norm](https://wandb.ai/wandb_fc/Normalization-Series/reports/Instance-Normalization-in-PyTorch-With-Examples---VmlldzoxNDIyNTQx#:%7E:text=In%20Layer%20Normalization%2C%20we%20compute,channel%20for%20a%20single%20example.)

[image]

##### From [group norm paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08494.pdf)

> Layer Normalization (LN) operates along the channel dimension

> LN computes µ and σ along the (C, H, W)
> axes for each sample.

[image]

##### Different Application Example

In [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LayerNorm.html) for NLP 3d tensor example mean and std instead are calculated over only last dim `embedding_dim`.

[In this paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/ICCV2021W/NeurArch/papers/Yao_Leveraging_Batch_Normalization_for_Vision_Transformers_ICCVW_2021_paper.pdf) it shows similar to pytorch doc example,

> almost all NLP tasks take variable length sequences as input, which is very suitable for LN
> that only calculates statistics in the channel dimension without involving the batch and sequence length dimension.

[image]

Example shown in [Another paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/shen20e/shen20e.pdf),

> LN normalizes across the channel/feature dimension as shown in Figure 1.

[image]

##### Manual Layer Norm with only Embed Dim

```
import torch

batch_size, seq_size, dim = 2, 3, 4
last_dims = 4

embedding = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_size, dim)
print("x: ", embedding)

layer_norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(last_dims, elementwise_affine = False)
layer_norm_out = layer_norm(embedding)
print("y: ", layer_norm_out)

eps: float = 0.00001
mean = torch.mean(embedding[0, :, :], dim=(-1), keepdim=True)
var = torch.square(embedding[0, :, :] - mean).mean(dim=(-1), keepdim=True)
y_custom = (embedding[0, :, :] - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + eps)
print("y_custom: ", y_custom)
assert torch.allclose(layer_norm_out[0], y_custom), 'Tensors do not match.'

eps: float = 0.00001
mean = torch.mean(embedding[1, :, :], dim=(-1), keepdim=True)
var = torch.square(embedding[1, :, :] - mean).mean(dim=(-1), keepdim=True)
y_custom = (embedding[1, :, :] - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + eps)
print("y_custom: ", y_custom)
assert torch.allclose(layer_norm_out[1], y_custom), 'Tensors do not match.'
```

##### Output

```
x:  tensor([[[-0.0594, -0.8702, -1.9837,  0.2914],
         [-0.4774,  1.0372,  0.6425, -1.1357],
         [ 0.3872, -0.9190, -0.5774,  0.3281]],

        [[-0.5548,  0.0815,  0.2333,  0.3569],
         [ 1.0380, -0.1756, -0.7417,  2.2930],
         [-0.0075, -0.3623,  1.9310, -0.7043]]])
y:  tensor([[[ 0.6813, -0.2454, -1.5180,  1.0822],
         [-0.5700,  1.1774,  0.7220, -1.3295],
         [ 1.0285, -1.2779, -0.6747,  0.9241]],

        [[-1.6638,  0.1490,  0.5814,  0.9334],
         [ 0.3720, -0.6668, -1.1513,  1.4462],
         [-0.2171, -0.5644,  1.6809, -0.8994]]])
y_custom:  tensor([[ 0.6813, -0.2454, -1.5180,  1.0822],
        [-0.5700,  1.1774,  0.7220, -1.3295],
        [ 1.0285, -1.2779, -0.6747,  0.9241]])
y_custom:  tensor([[-1.6638,  0.1490,  0.5814,  0.9334],
        [ 0.3720, -0.6668, -1.1513,  1.4462],
        [-0.2171, -0.5644,  1.6809, -0.8994]])
```

##### Manual Layer Norm over 4D Tensor

```
import torch

batch_size, c, h, w = 2, 3, 2, 4
last_dims = [c, h, w]

embedding = torch.randn(batch_size, c, h, w)
print("x: ", embedding)

layer_norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(last_dims, elementwise_affine = False)
layer_norm_out = layer_norm(embedding)
print("y: ", layer_norm_out)


eps: float = 0.00001
mean = torch.mean(embedding[0, :, :], dim=(-3, -2, -1), keepdim=True)
var = torch.square(embedding[0, :, :] - mean).mean(dim=(-3, -2, -1), keepdim=True)
y_custom = (embedding[0, :, :] - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + eps)
print("y_custom: ", y_custom)
assert torch.allclose(layer_norm_out[0], y_custom), 'Tensors do not match.'

eps: float = 0.00001
mean = torch.mean(embedding[1, :, :], dim=(-3, -2, -1), keepdim=True)
var = torch.square(embedding[1, :, :] - mean).mean(dim=(-3, -2, -1), keepdim=True)
y_custom = (embedding[1, :, :] - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + eps)
print("y_custom: ", y_custom)
assert torch.allclose(layer_norm_out[1], y_custom), 'Tensors do not match.'
```

##### Output

```
x:  tensor([[[[ 1.0902, -0.8648,  1.5785,  0.3087],
          [ 0.0249, -1.3477, -0.9565, -1.5024]],

         [[ 1.8024, -0.2894,  0.7284,  0.7822],
          [ 1.4385, -0.2848, -0.3114,  0.4633]],

         [[ 0.9061,  0.3066,  0.9916,  0.9284],
          [ 0.3356,  0.9162, -0.4579,  1.0669]]],


        [[[-0.8292,  0.9111, -0.7307, -1.1003],
          [ 0.3441, -1.9823,  0.1313,  0.2048]],

         [[-0.2838,  0.1147, -0.1605, -0.4637],
          [-2.1343, -0.4402,  1.6685,  0.4455]],

         [[ 0.6895, -2.7331,  1.1693, -0.6999],
          [-0.3497, -0.2942, -0.0028, -1.3541]]]])
y:  tensor([[[[ 0.8653, -1.3279,  1.4131, -0.0114],
          [-0.3298, -1.8697, -1.4309, -2.0433]],

         [[ 1.6643, -0.6824,  0.4594,  0.5198],
          [ 1.2560, -0.6772, -0.7071,  0.1619]],

         [[ 0.6587, -0.0137,  0.7547,  0.6838],
          [ 0.0188,  0.6701, -0.8715,  0.8392]]],


        [[[-0.4938,  1.2220, -0.3967, -0.7610],
          [ 0.6629, -1.6306,  0.4531,  0.5256]],

         [[ 0.0439,  0.4368,  0.1655, -0.1335],
          [-1.7805, -0.1103,  1.9686,  0.7629]],

         [[ 1.0035, -2.3707,  1.4764, -0.3663],
          [-0.0211,  0.0337,  0.3210, -1.0112]]]])
y_custom:  tensor([[[ 0.8653, -1.3279,  1.4131, -0.0114],
         [-0.3298, -1.8697, -1.4309, -2.0433]],

        [[ 1.6643, -0.6824,  0.4594,  0.5198],
         [ 1.2560, -0.6772, -0.7071,  0.1619]],

        [[ 0.6587, -0.0137,  0.7547,  0.6838],
         [ 0.0188,  0.6701, -0.8715,  0.8392]]])
y_custom:  tensor([[[-0.4938,  1.2220, -0.3967, -0.7610],
         [ 0.6629, -1.6306,  0.4531,  0.5256]],

        [[ 0.0439,  0.4368,  0.1655, -0.1335],
         [-1.7805, -0.1103,  1.9686,  0.7629]],

        [[ 1.0035, -2.3707,  1.4764, -0.3663],
         [-0.0211,  0.0337,  0.3210, -1.0112]]])
```

##### Example of custom layer norm implementation

```
from typing import Union, List

import torch


batch_size, seq_size, embed_dim = 2, 3, 4
embedding = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_size, embed_dim)
print("x: ", embedding)
print(embedding.shape)
print()


layer_norm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(embed_dim, elementwise_affine=False)
layer_norm_output = layer_norm(embedding)
print("y: ", layer_norm_output)
print(layer_norm_output.shape)
print()


def custom_layer_norm(
        x: torch.Tensor, dim: Union[int, List[int]] = -1, eps: float = 0.00001
) -> torch.Tensor:
    mean = torch.mean(x, dim=(dim,), keepdim=True)
    var = torch.square(x - mean).mean(dim=(dim,), keepdim=True)
    return (x - mean) / torch.sqrt(var + eps)


custom_layer_norm_output = custom_layer_norm(embedding)
print("y_custom: ", custom_layer_norm_output)
print(custom_layer_norm_output.shape)

assert torch.allclose(layer_norm_output, custom_layer_norm_output), 'Tensors do not match.'
```

##### Output

```
x:  tensor([[[-0.4808, -0.1981,  0.4538, -1.2653],
         [ 0.3578,  0.6592,  0.2161,  0.3852],
         [ 1.2184, -0.4238, -0.3415, -0.3487]],

        [[ 0.9874, -1.7737,  0.1886,  0.0448],
         [-0.5162,  0.7872, -0.3433, -0.3266],
         [-0.5459, -0.0371,  1.2625, -1.6030]]])
torch.Size([2, 3, 4])

y:  tensor([[[-0.1755,  0.2829,  1.3397, -1.4471],
         [-0.2916,  1.5871, -1.1747, -0.1208],
         [ 1.7301, -0.6528, -0.5334, -0.5439]],

        [[ 1.1142, -1.6189,  0.3235,  0.1812],
         [-0.8048,  1.7141, -0.4709, -0.4384],
         [-0.3057,  0.1880,  1.4489, -1.3312]]])
torch.Size([2, 3, 4])

y_custom:  tensor([[[-0.1755,  0.2829,  1.3397, -1.4471],
         [-0.2916,  1.5871, -1.1747, -0.1208],
         [ 1.7301, -0.6528, -0.5334, -0.5439]],

        [[ 1.1142, -1.6189,  0.3235,  0.1812],
         [-0.8048,  1.7141, -0.4709, -0.4384],
         [-0.3057,  0.1880,  1.4489, -1.3312]]])
torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: I found my problem: instea of computing `std = torch.std(embedding[0, :, :])`, I should do `std = torch.sqrt(torch.var(embedding[0, :, :], unbiased=False))`. The axis along which I computed mean and std is actually right.

Comment: @YQ.Wang you're right about using a biased estimator, but the axis in your example are actually wrong. The stats should be computed over the last dimension only, i.e. embedding[0, 0, :], not embedding[0, :, :]